# eksctl create iamserviceaccount with EKS add-on support for ADOT Operator

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, eksctl

I am attempting to install the AWS Distro for OpenTelemetry (ADOT) into my EKS cluster.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/adot-reqts.html

I am following this guide to create the service account for the IAM role (irsa technique in AWS):
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/adot-iam.html

When I run the eksctl commands:

```
eksctl create iamserviceaccount \
    --name adot-collector \
    --namespace monitoring \
    --cluster <MY CLUSTER> \
    --attach-policy-arn arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonPrometheusRemoteWriteAccess \
    --attach-policy-arn arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSXrayWriteOnlyAccess \
    --attach-policy-arn arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/CloudWatchAgentServerPolicy \
    --approve \
    --override-existing-serviceaccounts
```

I am getting this output:

```
2 existing iamserviceaccount(s) (hello-world/default,monitoring/adot-collector) will be excluded

iamserviceaccount (monitoring/adot-collector) was excluded (based on the include/exclude rules)

metadata of serviceaccounts that exist in Kubernetes will be updated, as --override-existing-serviceaccounts was set

no tasks
```

This Kubernetes service account does not exist in the target namespace or in any other:

```
k get sa adot-collector -n monitor
k get serviceAccounts -A | grep abot
```

Expected output:

```
1 iamserviceaccount (monitoring/adot-collector) was included (based on the include/exclude rules)
metadata of serviceaccounts that exist in Kubernetes will be updated, as --override-existing-serviceaccounts was set
...
created serviceaccount "monitoring/adot-collector"
```

When I check in the AWS Console under CloudFormation , I see that the stack was complete, with a message of "IAM role for serviceaccount "monitoring/adot-collector" [created and managed by eksctl]"

What can I do to troubleshoot this? Why is the Kubernetes service account not getting built?

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved after discovering there as a `ValidatingWebhookConfiguration` that was blocking the creating of service accounts without a specific label. Temporarily disabling the webhook enabled the Stack to run to completion, and the SA was created.